# Flurry Data Download processing over 24 hours for 1 event, 1 day

Tags: flurry-analytics

I am using https://dev.flurry.com/metrics/data-download, yesterday I tapped New Request, selected a date range of yesterday, add a filter of one parameter.  I saved.  Download Status = Processing, 24 hours later, Download Status is still Processing.
Is there an issue with Data Download?  I so wish Event Logs still existed.
If this is not the right place to ask this, could someone please tell me where I should post this?

None

None

24 hours and still processing.

Answer (score 0):

While large reports can take several hours to process, if a report is taking longer than expected, email support@flurry.com.